# Build mosquitto broker as static library

Tags: cmake, mosquitto

I want to build mosquitto broker as static library and integrate in my project. I need information to build. Please help me.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: And why does it need to be static?

Comment: My bad, I intended to ask how can i build mosquitto  broker as static library.

Comment: Apology for sin, i am new to cmake, still tried to update cmake in <repo>/src/cmakelist.tx file to add 
add_library(mosquitto_STATIC STATIC ${MOSQ_LIB})
It builds the static library but wheni add this in my project, i see lots of linker err related to openssl.

Comment: Can any one help me?

Comment: On which platform are you working? windows, linux, or osx?

Answer (score 2):

Using cmake:

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto.git 
cd mosquitto
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DWITH_STATIC_LIBRARIES=ON ../
make
```

If you have ccmake installed, you simply need to set WITH_STATIC_LIBRARIES to ON and compile.

Libraries will be located in build/lib

It is interesting but on my computer both static (libmosquitto.a) and dynamic (libmosquitto.so) libraries have been built.

Comment: My bad, I intended to ask how can i build mosquitto  broker as static library.

Comment: Whenever I build it normally (not with static library), only a libmosquitto.so.1 file is generated. How come there isn't a libmosquitto.so file?
Also, how do I make it build a static library without using cmake? i.e. just with Makefile.

Comment: @Frak try passing WITH_SHARED_LIBRARIES=no

Comment: If only the compile actually worked :( You need apt-get install xsltproc, but then it fails later on with some really obscure compile error. :/ I don't understand why they don't release packages with static libraries.

Comment: xsltproc is needed for documentation, which is optional. To stop documentation from being build use `cmake -DDOCUMENTATION=OFF ../`.